# Convert StdPicture Transparency Colour to White

Tags: winapi, vb6, bitmap, png, bitblt

I am using a [CodeJock ImageManager component](http://www.codejock.com//products/commandbars/tour_52.asp?platform=com) to hold a variety of images. I want to put one of these images into a FlexGrid Cell.

The Images I have are Png format and have transparent backgrounds so when I load the image into the grid like so:

```
Grid.Cell(flexcpPicture, 123, 4) = _
ImageManagerControl.Icons.GetImage(ImageNum, 16).CreatePicture(xtpImageNormal)
```

the background which in the original image was transparent is now black:
[image] (the same happens if I load the image into a PictureBox using the above method)

According to the documentation `CreatePicture` returns an [StdPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267231%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) object, is there some way I can convert this image (using BitBlt perhaps) so that the black is white? I'm not sure if this even possible?

I only need to do this with about three images so if I have to load them into an ImageList or something else first that would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps at all, but I've been playing around with the PictureBox.  I put two picture boxes on a form, put a bmp file (this only works with bmp files, so it might not be helpful to you), and did this:

```
Picture2.PaintPicture Picture1.Picture, 0, 0, opcode:=vbNotSrcCopy
```

Which successfully inverted the bitmap.  Here are the RasterOp constants: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243035(v=vs.60).aspx